# Official download 12.04 gives 730MB

Tags: 12.04, cd

Contrary to widespread information DOES NOT FIT ON A CD.
Download here was tut.fi. Is there a 700MB version somewhere?

Comment: Or just burn the file to a DVD. What difference does it make?

Comment: Or install from USB?

Answer (score 0):

Download ubuntu minimal CD from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD). It has the minimal stuff you need, and it's very small. However, you need internet connection to install ubuntu this way. If you don't like text-based installer, you can download [this older version of 12.04](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/), and then update. This version fits on 700MB CD, I tested it myself.